# Who is speaking over the end credits of Argo?

Tags: argo

During the end credits of Argo a man speaks about the events of the film. Who is the speaker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Argos imdb site](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1024648/trivia?tab=cz) this is from an interview with Jimmy Carter:

> Past the photos of cast members and the real people they play, there's
>   audio from an interview with then-President Jimmy Carter talking about
>   the crisis.